# Tooltip hover not working in IE11

Tags: jquery, html, css

This page worked with a hover tooltip in IE9 but doesn't do anything at all in IE11 Enterprise mode with Compatibility View settings to work like IE8:

Can someone help explain why IE11 is treating it differently?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">


<head>

 <meta charset='UTF-8'>
 <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
 <meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
 <meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" /> 

 <title>Current Payroll Status</title>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.0/jquery.min.js"></script>


 <style>

.hover {
    position:relative;
    left:1px;
}

.tooltip { /* hide and position tooltip */
  top:-10px;
  background-color:black;
  color:white;
  border-radius:5px;
  opacity:0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -moz-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -ms-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  -o-transition: opacity 0.5s;
  transition: opacity 0.5s;
}

.hover:hover .tooltip { /* display tooltip on hover */
    opacity:1;
}
 </style>

</head>


<body>
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="40%">

 <TR>

  <TD rowspan="1" colspan="1" valign="top" width="33%"><center>

   <div class="hover">Payroll Calculation<div class="tooltip"></center>

    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" width="100%">

     <TR><TD>Avg Runtime:</TD><TD>49.89m</TD></TR>

    </table>

   </div></div>

  </TD>
 </TR>

</table>

</body>
```

Comment: Trim you sample code, provide a http://codepen.io/pen/

Comment: Done. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the stray `<center> </center>` from your html code:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" width="40%">

    <TR>

        <TD rowspan="1" colspan="1" valign="top" width="33%">

            <div class="hover">Payroll Calculation<div class="tooltip">

                <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" width="100%">

                    <TR><TD>Avg Runtime:</TD><TD>49.89m</TD></TR>

                </table>

            </div></div>

        </TD>
    </TR>

</table>
```

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/aNovLr

Comment: that did it! Thanks!